# My pygame game does not start as it throws up an error, how do i fix it?

Tags: python, installation, pygame

This is supposed to pull up a pygame window.
All it says is no module named pygame, how can I possibly solve this?

```
pygame.init()
screenwdith=800
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((screenwidth,400),0,32)
```

Comment: go install pygame module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to install pygame.

See http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml
remember to use the right one for your version of pygame

then say: import pygame at the beginning of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Install the correct version of pygame for your version of python

http://pygame.org/download.shtml